# Вывод пагинации WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста, можно ли без перезагрузки страницы (в рамках `<div class="services__tab-item">`) сделать пагинацию для `<li class="posts">` сохранив нынешнюю `HTML` структуру? На данный момент выводится `1 2 3 вперед »` но при нажатии на любую из ссылок, переходит на `/page/2/` и там 404 ошибка.

```
<div class="tab_content">

<?php $cats = get_categories(array('taxonomy'=>'services_cat')); // get list of categories
 foreach ($cats as $cat) { ?>
   <div class="services__tab-item">
                           
    <ul class="services__tab-points">

     <?php
        $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'services',
            'posts_per_page' => 8,
            'paged'          => $paged,
            'tax_query' => array(             
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'services_cat',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => array( $cat -> term_id )
                    ),
                  )
                );
             $query = new WP_Query($args);

             if ($query->have_posts()) {
             while ($query->have_posts()) {
             $query->the_post();
             ?>

             <li>
              <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
               <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
               <span><?php the_permalink(); ?></span>
              </a>
             </li>

            <?php
             }
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();

            ?>

            </ul>

            <?php kama_pagenavi($before = '', $after = '', $echo = true, $args = array(), $wp_query = $query); // пагинация, функция нах-ся в function.php ?>
            
        </div>
      <?php } ?>

   </div>
```

Comment: кончено можно, https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/ пример реализации пагинации, только сделайте с использованием ajax

Comment: @DarthKYL Изменила код и вопрос, может поможете?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы уйти от неясностей, где и как расположен код, я написал плагин, который содержит весь необходимый код в себе самом.

Создайте папку `wp-content/plugins/so-ajax-pagination`. В ней создайте файл `so-ajax-pagination.php` со следующим содержимым:

```
<?php
/**
 * SO Ajax Pagination Plugin.
 *
 * @package           so-ajax-pagination
 * @author            KAGG Design
 * @license           GPL-2.0-or-later
 * @wordpress-plugin
 *
 * Plugin Name:       So Ajax Pagination
 * Plugin URI:        https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1251936
 * Description:       Pagination in taxonomies with ajax.
 * Version:           1.0.0
 * Requires at least: 5.1
 * Requires PHP:      5.6.20
 * Author:            KAGG Design
 * Author URI:        https://kagg.eu/
 * License:           GPL v2 or later
 * License URI:       https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain:       so-ajax-pagination
 * Domain Path:       /languages/
 */

/**
 * Class SO_Ajax_Pagination.
 */
class SO_Ajax_Pagination {
    /**
     * Script handle.
     */
    const HANDLE = 'so-ajax-pagination';

    /**
     * Ajax action name.
     */
    const ACTION = 'so-ajax-pagination';

    /**
     * Post type to show.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $post_type = 'services';

    /**
     * Taxonomy to show.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $taxonomy = 'services_cat';

    /**
     * Url of the page when shortcode fired.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * SO_Ajax_Pagination constructor.
     */
    public function __construct() {
        add_shortcode( 'services_cat', [ $this, 'services_cat_shortcode' ] );
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', [ $this, 'services_cat_script' ] );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_' . self::ACTION, [ $this, 'ajax_action' ] );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . self::ACTION, [ $this, 'ajax_action' ] );
    }

    /**
     * Shortcode [services_cat]
     */
    public function services_cat_shortcode() {
        ob_start();

        ?>
        <div class="tab_content">
            <?php
            $cats = get_categories( [ 'taxonomy' => $this->taxonomy ] ); // Get list of categories.
            foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ?: 1;
                $this->show_cat_posts( $cat->term_id, $paged );
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Enqueue plugin script.
     */
    public function services_cat_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            self::HANDLE,
            untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) . '/so-ajax-pagination.js',
            [ 'jquery' ],
            '1.0.0',
            true
        );

        wp_localize_script(
            self::HANDLE,
            'SOAjaxPaginationObject',
            [
                'ajaxURL' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'action'  => self::ACTION,
                'nonce'   => wp_create_nonce( self::ACTION ),
                'url'     => get_the_permalink(),
            ]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Ajax action.
     */
    public function ajax_action() {
        if (
        ! wp_verify_nonce(
            filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'nonce', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ),
            self::ACTION
        )
        ) {
            wp_send_json_error( __( 'Bad nonce!', 'kagg-pagespeed-module' ) );
        }

        ob_start();

        $term_id   = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'termId', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
        $page      = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
        $this->url = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'url', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );

        $this->show_cat_posts( $term_id, $page );

        wp_send_json_success( ob_get_clean() );
    }

    /**
     * Show category posts.
     *
     * @param int $term_id Category id.
     * @param int $paged   Pagination page.
     */
    private function show_cat_posts( $term_id, $paged ) {
        ?>
        <div class="services__tab-item" data-cat="<?php echo esc_attr( $term_id ); ?>">
            <ul class="services__tab-points">
                <?php

                $args = [
                    'post_type'      => $this->post_type,
                    'posts_per_page' => 8,
                    'paged'          => $paged,
                    // phpcs:ignore WordPress.DB.SlowDBQuery.slow_db_query_tax_query
                    'tax_query'      => [
                        [
                            'taxonomy' => $this->taxonomy,
                            'field'    => 'id',
                            'terms'    => [ $term_id ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ];

                $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                        $query->the_post();
                        ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                <p><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <?php
                    }
                }

                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
            add_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', [ $this, 'get_pagenum_link_filter' ], 10, 2 );
            $this->kama_pagenavi( [], $query ); // Пагинация.
            remove_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', [ $this, 'get_pagenum_link_filter' ], 10 );
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Filters the page number link for the current request.
     *
     * @param string $result  The page number link.
     * @param int    $pagenum The page number.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get_pagenum_link_filter( $result, $pagenum ) {
        if ( ! wp_doing_ajax() ) {
            return $result;
        }

        $result = str_replace( admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), $this->url, $result );
        $result = preg_replace( '/\?paged=(.+)/', '/page/$1/', $result );

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Альтернатива wp_pagenavi. Создает ссылки пагинации на страницах архивов.
     *
     * @param array  $args     Аргументы функции.
     * @param object $wp_query Объект WP_Query на основе которого строится пагинация. По умолчанию глобальная переменная
     *                         $wp_query.
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @author  Тимур Камаев
     * @link    Ссылка на страницу функции: http://wp-kama.ru/?p=8
     * @version 2.7
     */
    private function kama_pagenavi( $args = [], $wp_query = null ) {
        // Параметры по умолчанию.
        $default = [
            'before'          => '', // Текст до навигации.
            'after'           => '', // Текст после навигации.
            'echo'            => true, // Возвращать или выводить результат.
            'text_num_page'   => '',
            // Текст перед пагинацией.
            // {current} - текущая.
            // {last} - последняя (пр: 'Страница {current} из {last}' получим: "Страница 4 из 60").
            'num_pages'       => 10,
            // Сколько ссылок показывать.
            'step_link'       => 10,
            // Ссылки с шагом (если 10, то: 1,2,3...10,20,30. Ставим 0, если такие ссылки не нужны.
            'dotright_text'   => '…',
            // Промежуточный текст "до".
            'dotright_text2'  => '…',
            // Промежуточный текст "после".
            'back_text'       => '« назад',
            // Текст "перейти на предыдущую страницу". Ставим 0, если эта ссылка не нужна.
            'next_text'       => 'вперед »',
            // Текст "перейти на следующую страницу".  Ставим 0, если эта ссылка не нужна.
            'first_page_text' => '« к началу',
            // Текст "к первой странице".    Ставим 0, если вместо текста нужно показать номер страницы.
            'last_page_text'  => 'в конец »',
            // Текст "к последней странице". Ставим 0, если вместо текста нужно показать номер страницы.
        ];

        $fargs = func_get_args();
        if ( $fargs && is_string( $fargs[0] ) ) {
            $default['before'] = isset( $fargs[0] ) ? $fargs[0] : '';
            $default['after']  = isset( $fargs[1] ) ? $fargs[1] : '';
            $default['echo']   = isset( $fargs[2] ) ? $fargs[2] : true;
            $args              = isset( $fargs[3] ) ? $fargs[3] : [];
            $wp_query          = $GLOBALS['wp_query']; // После определения $default!
        }

        if ( ! $wp_query ) {
            wp_reset_postdata();
            global $wp_query;
        }

        if ( ! $args ) {
            $args = [];
        }

        if ( $args instanceof WP_Query ) {
            // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
            $wp_query = $args;
            $args     = [];
        }

        $default = apply_filters( 'kama_pagenavi_args', $default ); // Чтобы можно было установить свои значения по умолчанию.

        $rg = (object) array_merge( $default, $args );

        $paged    = (int) $wp_query->get( 'paged' );
        $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

        // Проверка на надобность в навигации.
        if ( $max_page <= 1 ) {
            return false;
        }

        if ( empty( $paged ) || 0 === $paged ) {
            $paged = 1;
        }

        $pages_to_show         = (int) $rg->num_pages;
        $pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show - 1;

        $half_page_start = (int) floor( $pages_to_show_minus_1 / 2 ); // Сколько ссылок до текущей страницы.
        $half_page_end   = (int) ceil( $pages_to_show_minus_1 / 2 ); // Сколько ссылок после текущей страницы.

        $start_page = $paged - $half_page_start; // Первая страница.
        $end_page   = $paged + $half_page_end;   // Последняя страница (условно).

        if ( $start_page <= 0 ) {
            $start_page = 1;
        }

        if ( ( $end_page - $start_page ) !== $pages_to_show_minus_1 ) {
            $end_page = $start_page + $pages_to_show_minus_1;
        }

        if ( $end_page > $max_page ) {
            $start_page = $max_page - $pages_to_show_minus_1;
            $end_page   = (int) $max_page;
        }

        if ( $start_page <= 0 ) {
            $start_page = 1;
        }

        // Создаем базу чтобы вызвать get_pagenum_link один раз.
        $link_base = str_replace( 99999999, '___', get_pagenum_link( 99999999 ) );
        $first_url = get_pagenum_link( 1 );
        if ( false === strpos( $first_url, '?' ) ) {
            $first_url = user_trailingslashit( $first_url );
        }

        // Собираем елементы.
        $els = [];

        if ( $rg->text_num_page ) {
            $rg->text_num_page = preg_replace( '!{current}|{last}!', '%s', $rg->text_num_page );
            $els['pages']      = sprintf( '<span class="pages">' . $rg->text_num_page . '</span>', $paged, $max_page );
        }
        // Назад.
        if ( $rg->back_text && 1 !== $paged ) {
            $els['prev'] = '<a class="prev" href="' . ( ( $paged - 1 ) === 1 ? $first_url : str_replace( '___', ( $paged - 1 ), $link_base ) ) . '">' . $rg->back_text . '</a>';
        }
        // В начало.
        if ( $start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $max_page ) {
            $els['first'] = '<a class="first" href="' . $first_url . '">' . ( $rg->first_page_text ?: 1 ) . '</a>';
            if ( $rg->dotright_text && 2 !== $start_page ) {
                $els[] = '<span class="extend">' . $rg->dotright_text . '</span>';
            }
        }
        // Пагинация.
        for ( $i = $start_page; $i <= $end_page; $i ++ ) {
            if ( $i === $paged ) {
                $els['current'] = '<span class="current">' . $i . '</span>';
            } elseif ( 1 === $i ) {
                $els[] = '<a href="' . $first_url . '">1</a>';
            } else {
                $els[] = '<a href="' . str_replace( '___', $i, $link_base ) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
            }
        }

        // Ссылки с шагом.
        $dd = 0;
        if ( $rg->step_link && $end_page < $max_page ) {
            for ( $i = $end_page + 1; $i <= $max_page; $i ++ ) {
                if ( 0 === $i % $rg->step_link && $i !== $rg->num_pages ) {
                    if ( 1 === ++ $dd ) {
                        $els[] = '<span class="extend">' . $rg->dotright_text2 . '</span>';
                    }
                    $els[] = '<a href="' . str_replace( '___', $i, $link_base ) . '">' . $i . '</a>';
                }
            }
        }
        // В конец.
        if ( $end_page < $max_page ) {
            if ( $rg->dotright_text && ( $max_page - 1 ) !== $end_page ) {
                $els[] = '<span class="extend">' . $rg->dotright_text2 . '</span>';
            }
            $els['last'] = '<a class="last" href="' . str_replace( '___', $max_page, $link_base ) . '">' . ( $rg->last_page_text ?: $max_page ) . '</a>';
        }
        // Вперед.
        if ( $rg->next_text && $paged !== $end_page ) {
            $els['next'] = '<a class="next" href="' . str_replace( '___', ( $paged + 1 ), $link_base ) . '">' . $rg->next_text . '</a>';
        }

        $els = apply_filters( 'kama_pagenavi_elements', $els );

        $out = $rg->before . '<div class="wp-pagenavi">' . implode( ' ', $els ) . '</div>' . $rg->after;

        $out = apply_filters( 'kama_pagenavi', $out );

        if ( $rg->echo ) {
            // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
            echo $out;
        } else {
            return $out;
        }

        return '';
    }
}

new SO_Ajax_Pagination();
```

В этой же папке создайте файл `so-ajax-pagination.js` со следующим содержимым:

```
/* global SOAjaxPaginationObject */

jQuery( document ).ready(
    function( $ ) {
        function onCLick( event ) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var cat_section = event.target.closest( '.services__tab-item' );
            var termId = $( cat_section ).data( 'cat' );
            var href = event.target.href;
            var page = href.split( '/page/' )[ 1 ];
            page = page ? page : '1';
            page = page.split( '/' )[ 0 ];
            $.post(
                SOAjaxPaginationObject.ajaxURL,
                {
                    action: SOAjaxPaginationObject.action,
                    nonce: SOAjaxPaginationObject.nonce,
                    termId: termId,
                    page: page,
                    url: SOAjaxPaginationObject.url
                },
                function( response ) {
                    $( cat_section ).html( response.data );
                    $( '.wp-pagenavi' ).click( onCLick );
                }
            )
                .fail(
                    function( response ) {
                        alert( response.data );
                    }
                );

            return false;
        }

        $( '.wp-pagenavi' ).click( onCLick );
    }
);
```

Активируйте новый плагин `So Ajax Pagination`.

В контент нужной страницы добавьте шорткод `[services_cat]`. Откройте эту страницу и убедитесь, что код работает.